# How do I create a loop based off this array?

Tags: php, input, foreach

I'm trying to process this array, first testing for the presence of a check, then extrapolating the data from quantity to return a valid price.

Here's the input for fixed amounts of items, with no variable quantity.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="measure[<?=$item->id?>][checked]" value="<?=$item->id?>">
<input type="hidden" name="measure[<?=$item->id?>][quantity]" value="1" />
```

Here's the inputs for variable amounts of items.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="measure[<?=$item->id?>][checked]" value="<?=$item->id?>"> 
<input class="item_mult" value="0" type="text" name="measure[<?=$item->id?>][quantity]" />
```

So, the resulting array is multidimensional. Here's an output:

```
Array ( 
[1] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) 
[3] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) 
...
[14] => Array ( [checked] => 14 [quantity] => 999 ) 
)
```

Here's the loop I'm using to take this array and process items checked off the form in the first place. I guess the question essentially boils down to how do I structure my conditional statement to incorporate the multi-dimensional array?

```
foreach($field as $value):  
            if ($value['checked'] == TRUE) { 

                $query = $this->db->get_where('items', array('id' => $value['checked']))->row();

                #Test to see if quantity input is present
                if ($value['quantity'] == TRUE) {
                    $newprice = $value['quantity'] * $query->price;

                    $totals[] = $newprice;  
                }

                #Just return the base value if not
                else { 
                    $newprice = $query->price;

                    $totals[] = $newprice; 
                }

            }
            else { } ?>

            <p><?=$query->name?> - <?=money_format('%(#10n', $newprice)?></p>

        <? endforeach; ?>
```

My question: How can I change my loop to work with the multidimensional array?

Comment: Is it working like this? Or is there some sort of false output?
Is `$field` the whole array or one row of it?

Comment: The foreach loop doesn't run, it breaks. I am looking for the right keys and values to 'foreach through', if I'm saying that right.

Comment: What errors/warnings do you get? The loop itself looks good to me (except a notice for checking for a not existent index `$value[checked]`, but that does not break the loop).

Comment: Undefined index: checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found at least 2 errors:

1. put a declaration of `$newprice` outside the scope of the main if, otherwise it is not avaiable outside it, in the `money_format` call
2. before checking the values of arrays, check if the value is set with the `isset` function.

So the code will be

```
foreach($field as $value):
            $newprice = 0;  
            if (isset($value['checked']) && $value['checked'] == TRUE) { 

                $query = $this->db->get_where('items', array('id' => $value['checked']))->row();

                #Test to see if quantity input is present
                if (isset($value['quantity']) &&  $value['quantity'] == TRUE) {
                    $newprice = $value['quantity'] * $query->price;

                    $totals[] = $newprice;  
                }

                #Just return the base value if not
                else { 
                    $newprice = $query->price;

                    $totals[] = $newprice; 
                }

            }
            else { } ?>

            <p><?=$query->name?> - <?=money_format('%(#10n', $newprice)?></p>

        <? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be comparing against true in an if statement. Simply use the bare expression and let PHP check its "trueness":

```
        if ($value['checked']) { 
            ....
            if ($value['quantity']) {
```

Comment: You're certainly right, but that doesn't break the loop as it is no type comparison.